# GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user) generates error Encryption Failed

Tags: asp.net-core

A call to `GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user)` method returns with the error message `Encryption Failed`

This is a .Net Core Application with a resource server and an authentication Server.The User Accounts Management is being done on the resource server. When execution gets to

```
 var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
```

I get the error message `Encryption Failed`

Below is the configuration for data protection

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(folderForKeyStore, "teejay.pfx"), "xxxxxxxxxx");
var folderForKeyStore = Configuration["Data:KeyStoreFolderWhichIsBacked:keystore"];
services.AddDataProtection()
           .SetApplicationName("Academic Records Management System")
          .ProtectKeysWithDpapiNG("CERTIFICATE=Hashid:" + cert.Thumbprint, flags: DpapiNGProtectionDescriptorFlags.None)
            .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(folderForKeyStore));
```

The following is the stack trace

```
at     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.UnsafeNativeMethods.ThrowExceptionForNCryptStat    usImpl(Int32 ntstatus)       at     Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.ProtectWithDpapiNGCore(NCryptDescriptorHandle protectionDescriptorHandle, Byte* pbData, UInt32 cbData)
   at     Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.ProtectWithDpapiNG(ISecret secret, NCryptDescriptorHandle protectionDescriptorHandle)
```

at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiNGXmlEncryptor.Encrypt(XElement plaintextElement)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.XmlEncryptionExtensions.EncryptIfNecessary(IXmlEncryptor encryptor, XElement element)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.IInternalXmlKeyManager.CreateNewKey(Guid keyId, DateTimeOffset creationDate, DateTimeOffset activationDate, DateTimeOffset expirationDate)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.CreateNewKey(DateTimeOffset activationDate, DateTimeOffset expirationDate)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.CreateCacheableKeyRingCore(DateTimeOffset now, IKey keyJustAdded)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.ICacheableKeyRingProvider.GetCacheableKeyRing(DateTimeOffset now)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingProvider.GetCurrentKeyRingCore(DateTime utcNow)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(Byte[] plaintext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.DataProtectorTokenProvider`1.<GenerateAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at ARMS.ResourceServer.Controllers.UserManagerController.d__25.MoveNext() in E:\Projects\School\ARMS\ARMS.ResourceServer\Controllers\UserManagerController.cs:line 271
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()

So after reading around for a while I manage to dig into the event viewer and this is what I found

[image]

One thing is obvious. There is definitely a problem with my self-signed Certifiates but what is not obvious is how to deal with this. Somebody help me PLEASE!!